# Setting each host vector's data element of type int array on device vector

Tags: c++, vector, stl, cuda, thrust

I'm trying to implement the following C++ function on CUDA Thrust:

```
void setFragment( vector< Atom * > &vStruct, vector< Fragment * > &vFragment ) {
    Fragment *frag;

    int n = vStruct.size();

    for( int i = 0 ; i < n-2 ; i++ ){
        frag = new Fragment();
        frag->index[0] = i;
        frag->index[1] = i+1;   
        frag->index[2] = i+2;   

        vFragment.push_back( frag );    
    }
}
```

To do so, I created a functor to set indices of each Fragment vector in the following way:

```
struct setFragment_functor
{
    const int n;

    setFragment_functor(int _n) : n(_n) {}

    __host__ __device__
    void operator() (Fragment *frag) {
        frag->index[0] = n;
        frag->index[1] = n+1;
        frag->index[2] = n+2;       
    }
};

void setFragment( vector< Atom * > &vStruct, vector< Fragment * > &vFragment ) {
    int n = vStruct.size();
    thrust::device_vector<Fragment *> d_vFragment(n-2);

    thrust::transform( d_vFragment.begin(), d_vFragment.end(), setFragment_functor( thrust::counting_iterator<int>(0) ) );

    thrust::copy(d_vFragment.begin(), d_vFragment.end(), vFragment.begin());        
}
```

However, I'm getting the following errors for the transformation that I applied:

```
1) error: no instance of constructor "setFragment_functor::setFragment_functor" matches the argument list
            argument types are: (thrust::counting_iterator<int, thrust::use_default, thrust::use_default, thrust::use_default>) 
2) error: no instance of overloaded function "thrust::transform" matches the argument list
        argument types are: (thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<Fragment *>>, thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<Fragment *>>, <error-type>)
```

I'm new to CUDA. I will appreciate if someone can help me to implement the C++ function on CUDA.

Comment: Why is d_vFragment a reference?

Comment: It's a reference to each Fragment vector instance. I want to copy them into the argument vector vFragment which is a reference as well.

Comment: Try it as an object, no &

Comment: Thanks. That resolved the error with initialization but I'm still getting the first and second errors

Comment: https://thrust.github.io/doc/group__transformations.html I don't see a prototype that takes three arguments.   Are you missing a some parameters?

Comment: Thanks! I added d_vFragment.begin() as the third argument as destination/store for an in-place transformation. It resolved the second error but I'm still getting the first one.

Comment: That code is obviously never going to work. Nowhere have you allocated memory for any of the Fragment structures, and the functor you have is not a model of a Unary functor. You asked in you last question whether this was a good candidate for the GPU -- it isn't, and you are wasting you time trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put it bluntly, the code you have written has several glaring problems and can never be made to work in the way you imagine. Further to that, I am guessing the rationale for wanting run a function like this on a GPU in the first place is because profiling shown it is very slow. And that slowness is because it is incredibly poorly designed and calls `new` and `push_back` potentially millions of times for a decent sized input array. There is no way to accelerate those functions on the GPU. They are *slower*, not faster. And the idea of using the GPU to build up this type of array of structures only to copy them back to the host is as illogical as trying to use thrust to [accelerate file I/O](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51320300/681865) was. There is literally no hardware or problem size where doing what you propose would be faster than running the original host code would be. The latency on the GPU and bandwidth of the interconnect between GPU and host guarantee it.

It is trivial to initialize the elements of an array of structures in GPU memory using thrust. The `tabulate` transformation could be used with a functor like this:

```
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/tabulate.h>
#include <iostream>

struct Fragment
{
   int index[3];
   Fragment() = default;
};

struct functor
{
    __device__ __host__
    Fragment operator() (const int &i) const { 
        Fragment f; 
        f.index[0] = i; f.index[1] = i+1; f.index[2] = i+2; 
        return f;
    }
};


int main()
{
    const int N = 10;
    thrust::device_vector<Fragment> dvFragment(N);
    thrust::tabulate(dvFragment.begin(), dvFragment.end(), functor());

    for(auto p : dvFragment) {
        Fragment f = p;
        std::cout << f.index[0] << " " << f.index[1] << " " << f.index[2] << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

which runs like this:

```
$ nvcc -arch=sm_52 -std=c++14 -ccbin=g++-7 -o mobasher Mobasher.cu 
$ cuda-memcheck ./mobasher 
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
0 1 2
1 2 3
2 3 4
3 4 5
4 5 6
5 6 7
6 7 8
7 8 9
8 9 10
9 10 11
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
```

But this is not a direct translation of the original host code in your question.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. We have to create Fragment instances because of our input PDB file data structure. If I use `thrust::device_vector<Fragment *> dvFragment(N);` applying your method, I get error such **internal_functional.h(322): error: no suitable conversion function from "Fragment" to "Fragment *" exists*

Comment: You can't use this method to initialize an array of pointers to structures.

Comment: Can you suggest me something? I tried raw pointer cast but that didn't work. I'll really appreciate if you can direct me to something.

Comment: @RafsanMobasher: Stop wasting your time on this. I am not sure how many times or ways I can tell you that this won't work in any sensible way

Comment: Thanks, I will. But it was still a great learning experience.